# Symbol Look up error: undefined symbol: _ZNSt8messagesIwE2idE

Tags: linux, gcc, libstdc++

I have an application build using gcc 4.9.2. I have **statically linked libstdc++ and libgcc** for compatibility issues. The program runs fine in many linux distributions I tested. But in one system I find the following error

```
Symbol Look up error: undefined symbol: _ZNSt8messagesIwE2idE
```

I've run c++filt on the errror which gives the result

> echo _ZNSt8messagesIwE2idE | c++filt

```
std::messages<wchar_t>::id
```

Running file command gives the following result

> file app

```
app: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped
```

Running ldd gives,

> ldd app
>               not a dynamic executable

But it is a dynamic executable. The same file runs on other similar machines.

uname gives

> uname -a

```
Linux el-rhel5-1 2.6.18-164.el5PAE #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:59:11 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

1. why am I getting "not a dynamic executable" message even though it is executable?
2. What does this error mean and what are the ways to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you statically linking the standard libraries exactly?  Maybe you should just build on the oldest system you plan to support?

Answer (score 0):

> why am I getting "not a dynamic executable" message even though it is executable?

`ldd` also gives that message if it doesn't recognise the file format, or some other error occurs.

Are you sure the file is exactly  the same as on the other machines? You could use `md5sum` to verify it's the same on every machine and hasn't got corrupted on the machine where `ldd` can't read it and it gives the symbol lookup error.